# Fetching users public data in android via Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

Just wanted to confirm,  it is not possible to fetch basic public profile data from users that are not friends of logged user, even if I have their profile ID?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the basic or Public profile information about any User or any object (Page, Event, Location etc.) from the Graph API.

Though there might be some difference depending upon the Access Token you would use, with App Access Token you would mostly get the All Public Data about any object, and with User's Access Token you might be restricted, if the User himself is restricted to access the Object.